# Почему мой контейнер кладет новые элементы в один и тот же участок памяти, если они добавляются не в пределах одной функции?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, c++11

Я написал примитивный гетерогенный контейнер для хранения пар: объекта future и целочисленного ключа, с помощью которого можно получить доступ к фьючу.

Код контейнера:

Базовый виртуальный класс:

```
class BaseContainer {
public:
    virtual void *get(int k) = 0;
    virtual bool is_key(int k) = 0;
    virtual void print() = 0;
};
```

Шаблонный класс, описывающий пару элемент-ключ:

```
template <class F>
class Pair : public BaseContainer {
    std::shared_future<F> f;
    int key;
    F value;
public:
    Pair (std::shared_future<F> _f, int _key):f(_f),key(_key){}
    void *get(int k) {
        if(k == key) {
            value = f.get();
            return &value;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Forbidden something or other..." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    bool is_key(int k) {
        return (k == key);
    }
};
```

Сам класс-контейнер:

```
class Container {
    std::vector<BaseContainer*> container;
public:
    template <class F>
    void push_back(Pair<F> &sb){
        container.push_back(&sb);
    }
    // функция возврата значения из контейнера по ключу
    template <class F>
    F get_data(int key) {
        void *ty;
        for(auto &t : container) {
            if(t->is_key(key)) {
                ty = t->get(key);
            }
        }
        F val = *(F *)ty;
        return val;
    }

    bool is_key_in_container(int key) {
        for(auto &a : container) {
            if(a->is_key(key))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

При добавлении в контейнер элементов последовательно в пределах одной функции, все работает отлично:

```
int main() {
    Container future_container;

    auto promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<int>>();
    auto promise2 = std::make_shared<std::promise<char>>();

    std::shared_future<int> future = promise->get_future();
    std::shared_future<char> future2 = promise2->get_future();

    std::thread th([promise = std::move(promise)](){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            count++;
        promise->set_value(count);
    });

    th.detach();

    std::thread th2([promise2 = std::move(promise2)](){
        int y = 95;
        promise2->set_value(y+5);
    });

    th2.detach();

    int key1 = 7, key2 = 78;

    Pair<int> pair(std::move(future), key1);
    Pair<char> pair1(std::move(future2), key2);

    future_container.push_back(pair);
    future_container.push_back(pair1);

    auto res1 = future_container.get_data<int>(key1);
    auto res2 = future_container.get_data<char>(key2);

    std:: cout << "Result: " << res1 << " " << res2 << std::endl;
}
```

Выводит в консоль:

```
Result: 10 d
```

Однако, если я вынесу добавление элемента в отдельную функцию:

```
class C {
public:
    Container future_container;

    template <class T>
    void foo(int key, int i) {
        auto promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<T>>();
        std::shared_future<T> future = promise->get_future();

        std::thread th([promise = std::move(promise), ii = i](){
            promise->set_value(ii+5);
        });

        th.detach();

        Pair<T> pair(std::move(future), key);
        future_container.push_back(pair);
    }
};

int main() {

    C c;
    c.foo<int>(4, 100);
    c.foo<char>(6, 100);

    auto res1 = c.future_container.get_data<int>(4);
    auto res2 = c.future_container.get_data<char>(6);

    std:: cout << res1 << " " << res2 << std::endl;
}
```

Программа начнет падать с segmentation fault, а отладчик покажет следующее (у обоих элементов контейнера один адрес):

[image: дебаг1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызывая `future_container.push_back(pair);` вы сохраняете в своем контейнере `std::vector<BaseContainer*> container;` указатель на локальную переменную, который становится невалидным как только переменная выходит из области видимости. Бросать потоки на произвол судьбы вызывая `th.detach();` тоже не следует.

Comment: Ну, `detach()` пока самое хорошее решение (Вручную контролировать время жизни). А так - это правда, спецификация не дает однозначного ответа на вопрос "Что лучше: `join` или `detach`". Так что я сам использую последний вариант.

Comment: @MrBin `detach()` - это как раз отказ от контроля времени жизни потока.

Comment: @VTT спасибо большое! Добавил семантику перемещения, чтобы переменная не умирала вместе с функцией, теперь все работает.